# RNA secondary structure comparison

Tags: bioinformatics, rna, structure-prediction

Do you know any program which can compare two and more different RNA secondary structures? I need find some (dis)similarities between lots of predicted secondary structures. And create maybe common sec. structure/shape.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [R-coffee](http://tcoffee.crg.cat/apps/tcoffee/do:rcoffee) of the T-coffee suite of tools. In general, the *coffee tools are excellent and work very well if you can get over their author's self obsession<sup>1</sup>. R-coffee can align RNA sequences taking into account structural information:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> The guy actually adds his name to the output of all his programs! Seriously, he does. Apart from being simply ridiculous, this also affects other programs you might want to pipe your data to. For example, I wanted to pipe t-coffee alignments to an alignment viewer and I had to parse out his effing name in order to be able to do it.

Comment: I was amused by your remark - but from what I can see, you'd only have to delete the second line of text.

Comment: @Superbest yes, isn't that enough? The default output of t-coffee is in clustal format, a standard and widely used format for alignments. Because of the author's self importance, I had to edit the output to remove his name before being able to view the alignment in another program. Just cause the guy likes to see his name written everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

there a number of tools in the Vienna package (RNAalifold, RNALalifold):
http://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/~ronny/RNA/index.html
some other tools are available from Freiburg Univ. such as:
LocARNA or CARNA (http://rna.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/CARNA/Input.jsp)